# Setting bounds for textLabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to populate each of my UITableViewCells with a question and each question is in an NSArray. The questions are wider than the iPhone screen can display and I'm having trouble figuring out how to display the question so it returns to the next line to display the entire question.

I originally went with a CustomCell class that inherited UITableViewCell and tried to display each question as a textView but I couldn't get my question to display at all.

My goal is to give each section of the UITableView 3 rows which would all be populated by a button for the user to answer each question.

[image]

Here is the code I have to populate my UITableView

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [survey.questions count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";
    /*
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *que = (NSString *)[survey.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = que;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    */

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    NSString *que = (NSString *)[survey.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Que Value: %@\n", que);
    cell.queLabel.text = que;
    cell.queLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


    /*
    if (numberOfSectionsInTableView.indexPath.section == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Button 1");
    }
    */

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: A couple things to consider if you are not seeing your cells populate. 1. Did you set your class with the delegate methods for the tableview as the delegate of the tableview? 2. In your main.storyboard (I'm assuming that's where your class with the tableview is defined) did you set the identifier for your custom cell the same as in your sample code? e.g. "MyCustomCell". and 3. did you set the tableview cell class in your main.storyboard file == to the custom class that you created in your nib? Also, you can layout your custom class for your tableview cell directly in your storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the word wrap with the following:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

If you want to add a button to the cell in the storyboard, create a new `.xib` file and lay out the cell that way.

Comment: I made the .xib file and created the layout so that there is a UIlabel above 3 uibuttons. I connected each IBOutlet to a property in my CustomCell class. I  made sure that MyCustomCell.xib had a custom class of the 'CustomCell' class I have.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the result afterwards. My table doesn't populate. I also updated the code I am now using after your suggestion

Comment: I use this to create the row from the `.xib`      `if (cell == nil){
        //initialize the cell view from the xib file
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: simpleTableIdentifier
                                                      owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }`